# I can't get integer into a range loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I've been trying to write a program that calculates factorial of a number between 1 and 10. I could make it calculate the factorial correctly but the problem is , it calculates the factorial even if number is greater than 10 or smaller than 1 without asking it again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {


    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num ;
        int factorial = 1;


        do{
            System.out.println("Enter an integer(1-10)  :");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }while(num>10 && num<1);


        for (int x = 1 ; x <= num ; x++)
            factorial = factorial * x;




        System.out.println("Factorial of number is " + factorial);



    } 
}
```

I tried to using `while` instead of `do-while` after declaring variable "num" as a random nubmer. But then it gave me the factorial of that random number.What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` loop condition is incorrect.  It can't be simultaneously greater than 10 and less than 1.  Use the logical-OR operator `||` to enforce your range:

```
}while(num > 10 || num < 1);
```

Comment: it makes no sense with and, I didn't even realize that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'while' condition isn't correct. Try :
while(num>10 || num<1);

Otherwise, it loops as long as the number entered is greater than 10 AND smaller than 1.